# How to add instance to viewstate with Add() method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've declare property tha has a viewstate with List of `TMP_RequestCourse` like this:

```
public List<TMP_RequestCourse> T_RequestCourse
{
   get
   {
      if (ViewState["TMP_RequestCourse"] == null)
         return new List< TMP_RequestCourse>();
      else
         return (List<TMP_RequestCourse>)ViewState["TMP_RequestCourse"];
    }
    set { ViewState["TMP_RequestCourse"] = value; }
}
```

but I couldn't add instance to it with this code:

```
   TMP_RequestCourse tmp = new TMP_RequestCourse();
   tmp.CourseCode = coursesSelector.SelectedValue.GetInteger().Value;
   tmp.CourseTitle = coursesSelector.SelectedText;
   T_RequestCourse.Add(tmp);
```

Actually, Add() method doesn't work.

Comment: Try following List<TMP_RequestCourse> courses = new List<TMP_RequestCourse>(); courses.Add(tmp_RequestCourse);

Comment: No, I want to add instance to T_RequestCourse(viewstate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
if (ViewState["TMP_RequestCourse"] == null)
     return new List< TMP_RequestCourse>();
```

you return new instance of `List<TMP_RequestCourse>` which don't exists in ViewState (no reference). Change it to:

```
if (ViewState["TMP_RequestCourse"] == null)
{
     var list = new List< TMP_RequestCourse>();
     ViewState["TMP_RequestCourse"] = list;
     return list;
}
```